# Why does String.Format work but SqlCommand.Parameters.Add not?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a `Project` table with two columns -- `ProjectId` and `ProjectName` -- and am writing a function that constructs and executes a `SqlCommand` to query the database for the ids of a Project with a given name. This command works, but is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements):

```
string sqlCommand = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} = {3}",
            attributeParam, tableParam, idParam, surroundWithSingleQuotes(idValue));

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, sqlDbConnection);
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    DataTable attributes = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(attributes);
    ...
}
```

`attributeParam`, `tableParam`, `idParam`, and `idValue` are all strings. For example, they might be `"ProjectId"`, `"Project"`, `"ProjectName"`, and `"MyFirstProject"`, respectively. `surroundWithSingleQuotes` surrounds a string with `''`, so `surroundWithSingleQuotes(idValue) == "'MyFirstProject'"`. I am trying to write this function as general as possible since I might want to get all of a given attribute from a table in the future.

Although the above String.Format works, this doesn't:

```
string sqlCommand = String.Format("SELECT @attributeparam FROM {0} WHERE " + 
    "@idparam = @idvalue", tableParam);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@attributeparam", attributeParam));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idparam", idParam));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idvalue", 
     surroundWithSingleQuotes(idValue)));

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, sqlDbConnection);
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
    DataTable attributes = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(attributes);
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure why. I get no error message, but when I fill my `DataTable` using a `SqlDataAdapter`, the DataTable contains nothing. Here are various approaches I've taken, to no avail:

- Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection) and [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx), using `AddWithValue` or using `Parameters.Add` and `SqlParameter.Value`.
- Selectively replacing `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, and `{3}`in `String.Format` with either the actual value or the parameter string.

In other places in my code, I've used parametrized queries (although with just one parameter) no problem.

Comment: The only piece parameters can directly replace is `{3}`.

Comment: You cannot use a parameter for the name of a column.  You will still have to use the `string.Format` for that, just like for the table name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically parameters in SQL only work for *values* - not identifiers of columns or tables. In your example, only the final parameter represents a value.

If you need to be dynamic in terms of your column and table names, you'll need to build that part of the SQL yourself. **Be very careful** for all the normal reasons associated with SQL injection attacks. Ideally, only allow a known whitelist of table and column values. If you need to be more general, I'd suggest performing very restrictive validation, and [quote the identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) to avoid conflicts with keywords (or prohibit those entirely, ideally).

Keep using SQL parameters for values, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid statement:
`SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn=@param`

Whereas this is not:
`SELECT * FROM @param`

This means that you can use parameters for values and not for table names, view names, column names etc.